# Language choices for writing very fast abstractions interfacing with Python?

Tags: java, c++, python, boost-python

I have a system currently written in Python that can be separated into backend and frontend layers. Python is too slow, so I want to rewrite the backend in a fast compiled language while keeping the frontend in Python, in a way that lets the backend functionality be called from Python. What are the best choices to do so?

I've considered cython but it's very limited and cumbersome to write, and not that much faster. From what I remember of Boost Python for C++, it's very annoying to maintain the bridge between languages. Are there better choices?

My main factors are:

- speed of execution
- speed of compilation
- language is declarative

Comment: How do you figure cython's not much faster? Are you declaring types? That's where the major speedup up is.

Comment: Cython, in fact is a very convenient tool to integrate python and "c code". It is not at all cumbersome. Simply, write those functions that would help speedup and expose them as library using cython.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

C++ with [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/) can generate all of the glue code you need. So long as you avoid excessive jumps between C++ and python it'll be as fast as your C++. SWIG interfaces are usually fairly straightforward to generate unless you're doing something "odd".

Comment: +1 I also recommend SWIG. It's _very_ easy to use. Not supported feature are **1/** Overloaded versions of certain operators (new, delete, etc.) **2/** Nested classes, and few other things, but there are workarounds and you will get clear warnings.

Answer (score 2):

If you used Jython you could call into Java back-end routines easily (trivially).  Java's about twice as slow as c and 10x faster than python last time I checked.

Comment: The problem is that the last time I check, jython was using a fairly antiquated version of python. Does it even have context managers yet?

Comment: @aaronasterling - It is indeed an old version, 2.5.2rc2 is the latest release. It does have context managers (I have a copy installed right now), but it's still lacking a lot of features that were included in 2.6 and 2.7, enough that I prefer dealing with maintaining boost-python bindings rather than using a release that's that old. :D

Answer (score 1):

I would disagree about Boost::Python. It *can* get cumbersome when wrapping an existing c++-centric library and trying not to change the interface. But that is not what you are looking to do.

You are looking to push the heavy lifting of an existing python solution in to a faster language.  That means that you can control the interface.

If you are in control of the interface, you can keep it python-friendly, and bp-friendly (IE: avoid problematic things like pointers and immutable types as l-values)

In that case, Boost::Python can be as simple as telling it which functions you want to call from python.